# Can I use the new Apple TV without a TV to play my Mac's audio to my stereo?

Tags: itunes, appletv, airport

I currently have an AirPort Express (Newest N version) that is connected to my AirPort Extreme Base Station via ethernet. I have no other use for it (printer, wifi extender, etc.) other than it being a conduit for my MacBook Pro's iTunes library to be streamed to my stereo and controlled by my iPhone, my wife's iPhone or any guests with iOS devices.

I was thinking about selling my AirPort Express and getting a new Apple TV if I can get the same functionality as my current setup. In addition to this potential setup, I don't lose anything, but actually gain all the features of the Apple TV (Netflix, iTunes Rentals, etc.) and the possibility of jailbreaking it to run XBMC or Plex.

1. I know the Apple TV can be controlled via the Remote app on my iPhone, but will I have to turn on the TV and wake up the Apple TV? If so, this is a small step, but annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stream music to my stereo via my AppleTV all the time without needing to turn on the TV, and control it via iOS devices. My current setup is AppleTV -> stereo via HDMI, and stereo -> tv via HDMI. The stereo turning on wakes up the AppleTV, but if the stereo is left on, starting to stream something via AirPlay also wakes up the AppleTV.